# How to prevent d3 brush events from firing after calling brush.move

Tags: d3.js, brush

I am displaying several identical charts (showing different datasets) side-by-side. Upon brushing on one chart, the brush should be replicated on all others.

Currently, I do this by calling `brush.move` on a `selection` of all charts excluding the currently brushed chart, as soon as someone brushes on a chart. This happens in a `brush`-type eventListener.

However, this `brush.move` triggers the `brush`-type event attached to the brush, leading to an error (or, more generally, an infinite loop).

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `d3.event` object to check what caused the update of the brush. From the API docs on [brush events](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush-events):

> ### Brush Events
>
> When a [brush event listener](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_on) is invoked, [d3.event](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#event) is set to the current brush event. The event object exposes several fields:
>
> - …
> - `sourceEvent` - the underlying input event, such as mousemove or touchmove.

If your brush is modified programtically, i.e. by calling `brush.move()`, the `d3.event.sourceEvent` property will be null, because no input event caused this update. In your event handler you can check this property to skip execution for programmatic changes:

```
if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return;
```

The same technique is employed by Mike Bostock in his [*Brush Snapping*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232537) Block. While handling the actual input event the brush is modified again to snap to the nearest value, which, obviously, should not trigger another run of the event handler.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! However, the `sourceEvent` property is not `null`. The `sourceEvent` in that case is a `brush` event. I adapted your solution: I use `d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush"`as a testing condition.

Comment: @nick Hm, that may be caused by your particular setup. Examining the Block I linked to, the `sourceEvent` unmistakably is `null` during the second run; the code wouldn't work if it was any different... Anyway, glad it helped to get you started.